# Can't boot Ubuntu after update to MacOS Sierra in dual boot with rEFInd

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, mac, refind

My macbook only boots to Mac after macOS Sierra update. The boot menu is not showing up so that I can use Ubuntu. I use rEFind

I tried to change boot order in `EFI/refind/refind.conf`, uncommenting `default_selection L,1`

Unfortunately nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that when I updated to macOS Sierra the rEFInd boot loader configuration was reset. After reinstallation of rEFInd the  problem was solved.

Comment: Technically it was not rEFInd's configuration that was reset; it was the EFI's boot order that was reset. Re-installing rEFInd was overkill, but fixed the problem. See [the "Keeping rEFInd Booting" page of the rEFInd documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) for more on this subject.

Comment: @RodSmith Thanks for correcting misunderstanding